# Number of prime Gauss integers in D(n,k)

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

I would like to know if, given two positive integers $n$ and $k$, it is possible to give an approximate expression for $N(n,k)$, where $N(n,k)$ stands for the number of prime Gauss integers inside the open disk of center $n$ and radius $k$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a satisfactory answer to the analogous question for the integers? 

Comment: Not yet. But I think there may be a link between the smallest $r$ such that $n-r$ and $n+r$ are both primes, let's note this number $r_{0}(n)$ if it exists, and $D(n,r_0(n))$. Maybe something like $r_0(n)=O_{\varepsilon}((D(n,r_0{n})^{1/2+\varepsilon})$. There is still a lot of work to manage to approach such a result though.

Comment: Of course I meant $O_{\varepsilon}(D(n,r_{0}(n))^{1/2+\varepsilon})$, sorry for the typing mistake.